# In datastax cassandra 5.1, why is dsetool missing insights_config command?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, datastax-startup

running `dsetool insights_config` on the DataStax Cassandra node returns `Unknown command: insights_config` whereas the [documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-dev/datastax_enterprise/tools/dsetool/dsetoolInsights_config.html) states that this command should be present.

Answer (score 1):

DSE Metrics Collector was introduced in the DSE 5.1.14 (current version is 5.1.17) - make sure that you're using version that has this functionality.  In my setup it works just fine:

```
(dse-5.1.17) ...\>dsetool insights_config --show_config
{
  "mode" : "DISABLED",
  "config_refresh_interval_in_seconds" : 30,
  "metric_sampling_interval_in_seconds" : 30,
  "data_dir_max_size_in_mb" : 1024,
  "node_system_info_report_period" : "PT1H"
}
```